# Replace all the occurences of a term in the files contained in a folder

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files

In a folder on my system, I have a `C++` project that I'm trying to compile.

This process uses some `C++` idioms which are not supported by my compiler version. In particular, often inside the code it is used the data value `'nullptr'`.

What I want to do is to replace all occurrences of `nullptr` with `NULL`.

I can do this in `VIM` with the command:

```
:%s/nullptr/NULL/g
```

How can I do this for all the files in a directory once, without opening each file and executing the command?

Comment: You may want to try `#define nullptr NULL` in a few headers instead.  Easier to do, and easier to undo (or qualify with `#ifdef`, something you may want to investigate WRT to C++ features and particular compilers).

Comment: Found a discussion of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496824/how-to-define-nullptr-for-supporting-both-c03-and-c11

Comment: The "C++ idiom" is in fact the new standard: C++11 http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73801/can-not-mount-drive-after-installing-windows-vista/.
I guess you're compiling in a special environment because GCC for example support the standard (at least partially) for quite a long time now. Isn't there a upgrade for your compiler that would allow you to use C++11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

#### vim

You can use vim from the command line like so:

```
$ vim -c "%s/nullptr/NULL/g|wq" foo.txt
```

Wrap in a for loop:

```
$ for i in *; do vim -c "%s/nullptr/NULL/g|wq" -- "$i"; done
```

#### Perl

```
$ perl -p -i -e 's/nullptr/NULL/g' foo.txt
```

Wrap in a for loop:

```
$ for i in *; do perl -p -i -e 's/nullptr/NULL/g' -- "$i"; done
```

Or simply:

```
$ perl -p -i -e 's/nullptr/NULL/g' -- *
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for file in /path/to/dir/*; do
  sed -i s/nullptr/NULL/g "$file"
done
```

This does not affect subdirectories, though.

**Edit 1**

The faster solution (with GNU):

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i s/nullptr/NULL/g
```

This would affect subdirectories (and dotfiles), too. Add `-maxdepth 1` if that is not wanted.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU tools:

```
grep -rlZ nullptr /path/to/dir |
  xargs -r0 sed -i s/nullptr/NULL/g
```

To avoid having to rewrite every file.

As always with `sed -i`, keep in mind that it may break links (hard and soft), alter the ownership and permission of files and change the sparseness and potentially other uncommon attributes of files. Also beware that versions of GNU `grep` prior to `2.12` follow symlinks when descending the directory tree with `-r`.