# Can not mount drive after installing windows vista

Tags: linux-mint, boot, hard-disk, grub2, boot-loader

I have searched for weeks now and have not found an answer to my question. Hopefully you guys can give me a push in the right direction :)

Ok, here is what happened:

- I have linux mint on a 1.5 TB hard drive (with all of my media on it), this is the 'every day' computer I use
- My brother is running linux and also wanted to run vista on his computer.
- I had a spare 500 GB hard drive I was going to use to put vista on and then just have two drives run inside his computer.
- I am a college student and had the drive with me at school so I put the drive in my computer, removed the linux mint 1.5 TB hdd and went along with the vista install on the 500 GB hdd. (I did this so all I had to do was pop it in his computer when I came home).
- Install went without a hitch (other than its windows) and I removed the 500 GB hdd and set it aside for my next trip home.
- I then reconnected the 1.5 TB hdd and the issues started to pop up (here they are in the order I've been getting them):
- When I start the computer like normal I get a message saying something about an Ubuntu GRUB version. And then it has a GRUB prompt.
- ^^Because of this I found that I probably needed to reinstall GRUB. So I booted up a live mint disk. I know I need to know where my / partition is but I wanted to double check. So I go to click on the volume on the desktop and it disappears.

This is where I've been stuck for a few weeks now. Any and all help is appreciated!

From lgeorget's request: I get to the part where I just mounted it, but my drive will not open for me to get files from it. Am I doing something wrong in the process?

Answer (score 2):

If you can boot on a liveCD, you can enter the `fdisk -l` command. It will show you all the partitions detected on your disk(s).

You can then mount a partition manually with the command `mount <device> <mount point>`. `<device>` is one of the partition `fdisk` detects (something like `/dev/sda1` for example) and `<mount point>` must be a existing directory (like `/mnt` for example).

To see which are the detected disks, you can look in your `/dev` folder for devices like `sd[a,b...]` or `hd[a,b...]`.